# Python - Get substring based on unknow text and known characters (result from parsed xml)

Tags: python, xml

I have a line from a parsed `xml` file:

```
 <ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>
```

I do not know that `ID` is the text in `<>` and `</>`. How can I handle this if I want to extract `'ID`' and `'0b10-bd-59-ac-bac'` separately? `re.search` requires you to know `'ID'`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import re

s = " <ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID> "

whole = re.findall("<.*?>.*</.*?>", s)[0]
inner = whole[whole.find(">") + 1: whole.rfind("<")]
outer = whole[whole.find("<") + 1: whole.find(">")]

print(whole)
print(inner)
print(outer)
```

Output:

```
<ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>
0b10-bd-59-ac-bac
ID
```

Where the expression `<.*?>.*</.*?>` is the pattern:

```
<{anything but a <}>{anything}</{anything but a >}>
```

---

To address the other pattern you provided in the comments, you can try:

```
import re

strings = ['<ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>', '<Type ref="acc-63-5c-bl-5b"/>']

for s in strings:
    outer = re.findall("(?<=<)[\w ]+", s)[0]
    for inner in re.findall("[\w-]+", s):
        if '-' in inner:
            break

    print("Outer", outer)
    print("Inner", inner)
```

Output:

```
Outer ID
Inner 0b10-bd-59-ac-bac
Outer Type ref
Inner acc-63-5c-bl-5b
```

Comment: Can pattern be searchable? Let’s say I have s= '<ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>', and s1= <Type ref="acc-63-5c-bl-5b"/>. I want to do the same for s1, get ‘Type ref’ and ‘acc-63-5c-bl-5b’ separately. I also have one or two more strings with different configuration. Can I loop through and match different patterns with if/elif/else?

Comment: @Miss.Pepper I added it.

Comment: I have two more configurations, s2 = <length multiplier="none" unit="m">28.536756216711005</length> and s3= <b0ch multiplier="none" unit="S"/>. I have tried creating a solution for these, but it does not work. Can you help me do the same for those? I would like to split the information into sets like: length multiplier: none, length unit: m, length: 28.53...  And same type for b0ch. Is this possible in a simple way?

Comment: @Miss.Pepper I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand. It would be very helpful if you posted this in a separate post, along with what you have tried for things to be more clear. You can link me to your post if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `re.search` following way

```
import re
text = "<ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>"
match = re.search(r'<([^>]*)>([^<]*)', text)
part1 = match.group(1)
part2 = match.group(2)
print(part1)
print(part2)
```

output

```
ID
0b10-bd-59-ac-bac
```

Explanation: I used capturing group, which are denoted by `(`...`)`.